# javascript if - else shortcut doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, shortcut, if-statement

I have a checkbox couple with values "new" or "existing" company.

```
$("input[name=company]:checked").val()
```

with jQuery shows me the value of the checked box.
Now if I do:

```
if ($("input[name=company]:checked").val() == "new") {
    is_new_company = true;
} else { 
    is_new_company = false; 
}
alert(is_new_company);
```

I get the correct booleans.
Doing the shortcut:

```
($("input[name=company]:checked").val() == "new") ? is_new_company = true : is_new_company = false;
```

I get nothing.. Why is that?

Comment: Shouldn't you just do `is_new_company = ($("input[name=company]:checked").val() == "new")`? I'm not even sure what happens when you put assignments in a ternary operation like that

Comment: It worries me that multiple people have now written `boolean-expression ? true : false` -- what's the point of that?

Comment: Not sure why this happens, but as others suggested, don't use the ternary operator to write statements: instead only write expressions with it (i.e. the part in a statement right of the assignment operator `=`). In other languages such as Java this will not compile at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just do:

```
is_new_company = $("input[name=company]:checked").val() == "new";
```

I tried your code on Firebug console and it works fine: (`input[name=q]` is the search box at the top right corner of this page)

```
var x;
$("input[name=q]").val() == "asd" ? x = "t r u e" : x = "f a l s e";
console.log(x);//worked as expected
```

By the way, I consider the following to be more readable (I'd use it only for non-boolean values, of course):

```
x = $("input[name=q]").val() == "asd" ? "t r u e" : "f a l s e";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
is_new_company = ($("input[name=company]:checked").val() == "new") ?  true : false;
```

Comment: -1: `condition ? true : false` is redundant and should really just be replaced by `condition`.

Comment: @Amber Downvotes seem a bit harsh; the answers are right, just (slightly) unnecessarily verbose

Comment: @Michael: I never mind removing downvotes if someone replies to a comment stating they fixed the redundancy, but I will downvote in the first place if it's redundant code, because redundant code is poor code.

Answer (score 0):

```
is_new_company = ($("input[name='company']:checked").val() == "new") ? true : false;
```

Comment: -1: `condition ? true : false` is redundant and should really just be replaced by `condition`.

Comment: I know that it operates correctly, that was not the reason for downvoting. The downvote was due to bad style.